# How update NuGet repository before each build

Tags: c#, nuget, network-drive

How can I update NuGet repository before each project build automatically (repository is located on network map)?

Comment: Do you mean [nuget update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)?

Comment: Actually no. I need to keep my repository on network drive update

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference) reference. You question is not very clear; try to add more relevant information.

Comment: The point of my issue is that my NuGet repository is located on a network map drive instead of a local drive. I will try to create a script with PowerShell. Thanks for Link.